# Upgrade to 21.04 breaks apt: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0: undefined symbol: XXH3_64bits_reset

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

I just attempted to upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04 using the graphical interface.

Installation produced an error, and now apt itself is broken, with the error message:

```
$ apt
apt: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0: undefined symbol: XXH3_64bits_reset
```

The error happens both with and without sudo.

On the other hand, `dpkg` still works fine. I tried reinstalling the xxhash package and the apt package with dpkg. Installation of those packages with dpkg is successful, but it does not fix the above error when running apt.

Comment: It was probably broken before the upgrade. Please share the output of `find  /usr/local/lib -type f` . If long use pastebin.

Comment: Result of ``find  /usr/local/lib -type f``: https://pastebin.com/kkqZv1SL

Comment: I was on 20.04 and everything apt-related was working smoothly. The upgrade 20.04->20.10 was successful (I did ``apt update`` before starting upgrading to 20.10, apt was not giving any error at that point). The upgrade 20.10->21.04 is the one that produced an error and corrupted apt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove locally compiled libraries by

```
sudo rm -v /usr/local/lib/libxxhash.a
sudo rm -v /usr/local/lib/libxxhash.so.0.6.5
```

and then retry running APT by command like `sudo apt-get check`.

And finally reinstall the above [library](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libxxhash) using normal deb-packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxxhash0 libxxhash-dev
```

Comment: Lifesaver. Thanks so much.